# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code=2 Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

When developing an iOS app I come across random (sometimes occurring, sometimes not) EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the following code:

```
import UIKit

class OrderTripDetailsController: UIViewController, OrderAware {

var order: Order?
var orderService = OrderService()

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var driverName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var autoColor: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var autoPlates: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var autoBrandModel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var map: YMKMapView!

// MARK: Actions

// MARK: Navigation
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let cab = order?.orderCab {
        autoColor.text = cab.cab.auto.color.name
        autoPlates.text = cab.cab.auto.plates
        driverName.text = cab.cab.driver.fullname
        autoBrandModel.text = "\(cab.cab.auto.brand) \(cab.cab.auto.model)"
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    orderService.controllerDelegate = self
    orderService.startSync()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    orderService.stop() // <-- this is the line that fails

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

// MARK: Order Aware
func setOrder(order: Order){
    self.order = order
}

}
```

### OrderService

Order Service is a class that starts timer and stops it. After stop is called, sometimes EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs

```
import Locksmith
import RealmSwift

class OrderService {

// MARK: delegates
var controllerDelegate: UIViewController?

// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()

var timer = NSTimer()

//MARK: Domain actions

//repeat every n time if any dfound
@objc func initOrderSync(timer:NSTimer) {
    func onRemoteReceived (order: Order) -> Void {
        debugPrint("remote received", order.id)
        if let o = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(OrderPo.self, key: order.orderHash) {
            if o.orderStatus != order.orderStatus {
                debugPrint("order status updated", order.id, order.orderStatus)
                OrderUtils.navigateToOrderStatus(order,
                                                 viewController: controllerDelegate!)
            }
            try! realm.write {
                o.orderStatus = order.orderStatus
            }
        }
    }
    if let authToken = AuthUtils.getToken() {
        let orders = getOrdersByStatuses(OrderUtils.activeStatuses)
        if orders.count > 0 {
            for o in orders {
                OrderRemoteService().getOrderFromRemote(o.id!, token: authToken, callback: onRemoteReceived)
            }
        } else {
            debugPrint("invalidating timer; no orders")
            stop()
        }
    } else {
        debugPrint("invalidating timer; no auth")
        stop()
    }
}


func startSync() {
    if !self.timer.valid {
        debugPrint("starting order sync", controllerDelegate?.restorationIdentifier)
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20, target: self, selector: Selector("initOrderSync:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else {
        debugPrint("sync is already started", controllerDelegate?.restorationIdentifier)
    }
}

func stop() {
    dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue, {
        if self.timer.valid {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            debugPrint("invalidated timer", self.controllerDelegate?.restorationIdentifier)
        } else {
            debugPrint("sync is already stopped", self.controllerDelegate?.restorationIdentifier)
        }
    })
}

// MARK: orders

func getOrders() -> Results<OrderPo> {
    return try! realm.objects(OrderPo.self).sorted("orderTime")
}

func getOrdersByStatuses(statuses: [String]) -> Results<OrderPo> {
    var qString = "'\(statuses.first!)'"
    if statuses.count > 1 {
        for s in 1...statuses.count-1 {
            qString += ",'\(statuses[s])'"
        }
    }
    return try! realm.objects(OrderPo.self).filter("orderStatus IN {\(qString)}").sorted("orderTime")
}
}
```

Could anyone help with any ideas why it might happen?

## Update 20.08.2016

Found out that OrderService is being deinitialised after 10 seconds for some reason.

Comment: but where? there is a line that crash, show us

Comment: you're right, sorry.  I added a comment on the line. It is: ` orderService.stop()`

Comment: Give your `OrderService()` class.

Comment: added OrderService()

Comment: Instead of checking for `valid` declare the timer as optional and set it to `nil` after the `invalidate` message. Then the timer is valid if it's not `nil`. This way is more reliable.

Comment: But it can not be `nil`, since it is declared during object construction.

Comment: That's why I wrote *Declare it as optional* ( for example `var timer : NSTimer?`). The default initializer `NSTimer()` is just like an empty envelope, it does nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't resolved the issue.